# Oracle trigger: SELECT INTO, no data found

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have the following table that describes which chemical elements each planet is composed of using percentage.

```
CREATE TABLE elem_in_planet
(
    id_planet INTEGER,
    element_symbol CHAR(2),
    percent_representation NUMBER CONSTRAINT NN_elem_in_planet NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_elem_in_planet PRIMARY KEY (id_planet, element_symbol),
    CONSTRAINT FK_planet_has_elem FOREIGN KEY (id_planet) REFERENCES planet (id_planet),
    CONSTRAINT FK_elem_in_planet FOREIGN KEY (element_symbol) REFERENCES chemical_element (element_symbol)
);
```

I'm trying to make a trigger that warns users when they add a new element to a planet and the sum of elements in that planet exceeds 100%. I came up with this.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER elem_in_planet_check
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON elem_in_planet
    FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    sum_var NUMBER;
    PRAGMA autonomous_transaction;
BEGIN
    SELECT SUM(percent_representation)
    INTO sum_var
    FROM elem_in_planet
    WHERE id_planet = :NEW.id_planet
    GROUP BY id_planet;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            sum_var := 0;

    IF sum_var > 100 THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('WARNING: Blah blah.');
    END IF;
END;
/
```

This code seems to throw the NO_DATA_FOUND exception every single time, even though I have inserted test data and when I run the SQL query alone, it works as expected.

I'm new to this and don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Not related to your question, but you don't need the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **NOT** inserted the row into the table, 2 reasons.

1. The trigger runs as part of the insert statement which has not
   completed. So the row does not exist.
2. You specified "PRAGMA autonomous_transaction" (AKA the create
   untraceable bug here statement), did you previously get a mutating
   table exception. So you cannot see any data inserted/updated/deleted
   by the current transaction.Further if an error did occur the row would still be inserted as you did not raise an error or re-raise the existing error.  I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [PLSQL block structure](https://www.plsqltutorial.com/plsql-block-structure/). For now you may want to try:

You could use an after statement trigger or after statement section of compound trigger  to make this test, do raise_application_error if sum > 100;

BTW as it stands your "if on sum_var > 100" runs only when an error occurs. Anything after the "EXCEPTION" and before END for that block runs only when a error occurs.

```
create or replace trigger elem_in_planet_check
    after insert or update on elem_in_planet
declare 
   error_detected boolean := False;
begin
    for planet in 
        (
         select id_planet, sum_var
           from (select id_planet, sum(percent_representation) sum_var
                   from elem_in_planet
                  group by id_planet
                )
         where sum_var > 100
        )
    loop
       dbms_output.put_line('Planet ' || planet.id_planet || ' at '|| planet.sum_var || '% resources exceed 100%');  
       error_detected:= True; 
    end loop; 

    if error_detected then 
            Raise_application_error('-20001', 'Planet resources cannot exceed 100%'); 
    end if;

end elem_in_planet_check;
```

Comment: I will make sure to read the linked page, thank you. I tried to use this code and now I get this when I try to insert over 100%: `ORA-20001: Planet resources cannot exceed 100% ORA-06512: at "SQL_JOKDWALXEOQAMSQXZEKJUKYGK.ELEM_IN_PLANET_CHECK", line 19
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721`. The line from the loop isn't printed at all. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: How did you call this routine. The error message is there "ORA20001: ..." That is the message the trigger generated. ORA-06512 indicated perhaps the calling routine didn't handle the exception thrown by the trigger. Running with stand alone inserts I had no problem.

Comment: I ran these two queries: `INSERT INTO elem_in_planet VALUES (1, 'Fe', 70); INSERT INTO elem_in_planet VALUES (1, 'O', 99);` Both planet with ID 1 and the chemical elements exist in their respective tables. The three errors were shown after I ran the second query.

_"The error message is there "ORA20001: ..." That is the message the trigger generated"_
Yes, the error message is there, but I'd expect the message between the loop statements to be printed out too, and for some reason it wasn't.

I'm running this on livesql.oracle.com, could that be a part of the problem?

Comment: The reason don't see the messsage is because it is going to dbms_output, not into the exception message. Make sure you have "set server output" or just after begin put in the line "dbms_outpit.enable(buffersize => null);" In a live environment that message would be inserted into a log table - with a procedure with autonomous transaction (one of very few reasons for it) because raise_application_error rolls back all rows inserted, it that error is not handled.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanation!